# Why doesnt my iteration work?

Tags: python, cryptography, iteration

```
def lol(plaintext,row,col,group):
    val=''
    for ch in range(0,1000000,group):

        if ch>=row*col: #reset value of ch to the next col 
            break
            val=val+''
            ch = ch - (row+1)*group +1
            continue
        if ch>(row+2)*group: #to prevent exceedimg
            break
        val=val+(plaintext[ch])
        return val #return encrypted message
print(lol("ILIKEDRINKINGLEMONADEWITHICEIN", 6,5,5))
```

Comment: Context: I am trying to encode a matrix cipher and the result is only an i the first character of that encrypted message why doest my iteration loop thru

Comment: Can you explain which bit isn't working? What is your expected output? Please update your question, not include the description in a comment. Please also see *[mcve]*.

Comment: could u check down below for the comments

Answer (score 0):

The first time your for loop runs, ch is 0, which does not meet either if your if statement conditions.

```
val=val+(plaintext[ch])
return val #return encrypted message
```

val gets set and your function returns immediately after setting one character.  Try unindenting your return statement:

```
def lol(plaintext, row, col, group):
    val = ''
    for ch in range(0, 1000000, group):

        if ch >= row * col:  #reset value of ch to the next col
            break
            val = val + ''
            ch = ch - (row + 1) * group + 1
            continue
        if ch > (row + 2) * group:  #to prevent exceedimg
            break
        val = val + (plaintext[ch])
    return val  # this now returns after the for loop finishes.
```

Comment: i have tried it but now what happens is that I get idemei essentially i get the first 6 encryptions but after I reset ch to 1 thru ch = ch - (row+1)*group +1 it churns out the first variable and then stops

Comment: ok so the problem is that after the ch has been reset I want the loop to continue till it resets again and so on till it meets the break condition in the second if statement

Comment: okay ch essentially then sticks to a single value after i reset it is there a way for ch to be part of the loop after

Comment: i want for the loop to start looping again after ch is assigned to a value so if i reset ch to 1 and group is 7 i want ch to loop again in steps of 7 rather than stagnating at 1